# Exponential function and residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> Show that singular point of function $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z^4}$ is a
>   pole and find the order $m$ of that pole and the corresponding
>   residue.

Here my question begins with the singular point $z_0=0$ is a singular point?

Because $f(z_0)=\frac{0}{0}$ is a indetermination.But continuing, by definition of my text, if $f$ have isolated singularity point at $z_0$ and $k$ it's lower integer such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(z)$ exists, then $f(z)$ have pole of order $k$ at $z_0$

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}(z-0)^3\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z^4}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z}=^{L'H}\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{-2e^{2z}}{1}=-2$$
then $f(z)$ have pole of order $k=3$ at $z_0$, and $\phi(z)=\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z}$
$$Res(f;z_0)=\frac{\phi^{(k-1)}(z_0)}{(k-1)!}$$
$\phi^{(k-1)}=\frac{e^{2z}(-4z^2+4z-2)+2}{z^3}$

and there is a problem.

Comment: @ajotatxe fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's probably easiest to write out the Laurent series.  If you know the Taylor series for the exponential function, you easily get
$$f(z)=-\frac{2}{z^3}-\frac2{z^2}-\frac{\frac43}{z}-\cdots$$
which shows that $z=0$ is a pole of order $3$ with residue $-\frac43$.

---

**Comment**.  Also, imagine the function was
$$g(z)=\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z^{444}}\ .$$
Then the "differentiation" method is awful, whereas this method is still very simple.